# Sendkeys on link in webriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to do `sendkeys` on link using WebDriver? There are some elements on my webpage which are not accessible except by hitting tab. So I want to hit tab after getting focus on a link next to it. This was possible in SilkTest International, so hoping there must be a way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way for you to send keys (in Java):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions = actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT,"T")); // Open Firefox Tool Menu
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    actions = actions.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN); // Click Arrow-Down
actions = actions.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); // Click Return
actions.build().perform(); // Perform all the above
```

In your case, it sounds to me that you can simply do:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions = actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
actions.build().perform();
```

P.S.: There should be a way to access EVERY element on the page, so you might wanna focus your efforts on finding how to do it directly with your web-driver object first. Perhaps the element that you are looking for is "hidden" in an iframe or something... just a thought...